# numberstringnum{counter}: "Missing number" error

Tags: errors, counters, fmtcount

I'm experiencing problems to use fmtcount. The code bellow return "Missing number, treated as zero" error.

```
\numberstringnum{count} 
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\newcounter{count}
\setcounter{count}{1200}
\total{count}
\numberstringnum{count}
```

numerstringnum with a number instead a counter, works

```
\numberstringnum{1200}
```

Complete error message

```
Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   c
l.73 \numberstringnum{count}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just pass the counter. You have to pass the value of the counter:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fmtcount}

\begin{document}

\numberstringnum{1100}% one thousand one hundred

\newcounter{count}
\setcounter{count}{1200}
\numberstringnum{\value{count}}% one thousand two hundred

\end{document}
```

Comment: Or use `\numberstring{count}` instead.